# Why does viewing the Winter Bash hats on a Meta Stack Overflow user profile page redirect to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Why does viewing the Winter Bash hats of a user on a Meta Stack Overflow [user profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current) page redirect the user to Stack Overflow's [user activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Winter Bash is something that happens almost exclusively on the main site. While some hats [can](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/member-of-the-hand) or [must](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/freehand-circle) be earned on Meta Stack Overflow, it's something that is stored on a level which combines Stack Overflow *and* Meta Stack Overflow, and similarly for other sites in the network. The [leaderboards](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/) are per site as well; Meta Stack Overflow does not have its own entry.

Winter Bash is not unique in this respect: Meta Stack Overflow's Help Center: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/ redirects to the main site as well.